# Does Colossians 1:18 refer to Mortals or Corpses as the Dead "nekron" (νεκρῶν)?

Tags: greek, authorial-intent, colossians

If Jesus is "Firstborn" (πρωτότοκος) "out from the Dead" (ἐκ τῶν νεκρῶν) as stated by Paul & Timothy in [Colossians 1:18], and not conceived from "a man" | ἄνδρα (andra) as stated in [Luke 1:34], but born to Virgin Mary then Jesus came "out from [Mortals]" who are considered the "nekron" (νεκρῶν) | "the Dead"?

**If "Firstborn" out from the "nekron" (νεκρῶν) does not refer to Jesus' physical birth, and Mary a [Mortal] is not considered "the Dead", then does "nekron" (νεκρῶν) refer to Corpses?**

- If the "Resurrected" are those "born from the Dead", then Lazarus [John 11:38-44] would actually be the Firstborn from the Dead, so [Colossians 1:18] must not simply refer to the Resurrected.

Interlinear Sources :

- Colossians 1:18 [https://biblehub.com/interlinear/colossians/1-18.htm];
- Luke 1:34 [https://biblehub.com/interlinear/luke/1-34.htm];

Comment: I've always thought it referred to his death. Before the resurrection.

Comment: @curiousdannii - If the Resurrected are born from the Dead, then Lazarus [John 11:38-44] would be the Firstborn from the Dead - correct?

Comment: Chronologically, but not causally. Or thematically - he's the firstborn because in the resurrection he brings to us, we can become his adopted brothers and sisters.

Comment: Christ resurrected to immortal life; Lazarus, and others before him, simply resurrected to mortal life, since they died while still relatively young (the son of the widow who hosted Elijah, the son of the widow resurrected by Christ, etc).

Comment: @Lucian - so those Resurrected to mortal life died again but lived to a full 120 years? | Still does not answer what "nekron" refers to.

Comment: @חִידָה: Doubtful, but presumably they lived to an old age (Psalm 90:10). As already stated, it (obviously) refers to His resurrection from the dead.

Comment: You are Resurrected into a *new* body. To be resurrected, you need to come back ‘new’. That’s what it means. (Therefore) Lazarus was *not* resurrected, he was brought back to life - back into his (old) body.

Comment: And Jesus was the firstborn - but if you go back and re-read about it, he was the firstborn of creation. That is, ‘firstborn’ does *not* refer to being born as a ‘man’. So Mary doesn’t come into it.

Comment: For me it seems, possibly, and this is not my own invention, it talks about "the resurrection of the dead", and this "ek toon nekroon" is just that. He was the firstborn of the new creation, which comes through the resurrection of the dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to interpret Colossians except by bringing in the theology of death, resurrection, and the role of Christ, otherwise the claims made in Colossians about the godhead of Christ will seem too fantastical.

## The Death and the Promise

Through Adam, sin and thus death entered the world ("thou shalt surely die"), and Adam's offspring were thus also dead ("brood of vipers" in Matt 23.33 or John 8.44). But there was at the same time a Promise of deliverance in Genesis 3.15:

> And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed
> and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his
> heel.

It is this deliverance that is the true resurrection, and other forms of resurrection are types of this one.

Of course, a woman has no seed, so this is also a prophecy of the virgin birth. And over time, the Promise of that seed passed to Seth and Noah and eventually to Abraham, where it was again re-iterated "From thy seed will all the nations of the earth be blessed", and it was again confirmed to Jacob, and it was confirmed again to David.  Always the Promise of the seed kept passing until the appointed time when Christ was born.

### Physical Resurrections before Christ

Now before the birth of Christ, the Bible records three physical resurrections all by Elijah/Elisha and by touching their body in death or rest:

- The widow's son in 1 Kgs 17:17–22 when he is placed on Elijah's bed and Elijah covers him with his own body.

> And he said unto her, Give me thy son. And he took him out of her
> bosom, and carried him up into a loft, where he abode, and laid him
> upon his own bed. [...] And he stretched himself upon the child three times,
> and cried unto the LORD, and said, O LORD my God, I pray thee, let
> this child’s soul come into him again. And the LORD heard the voice of
> Elijah; and the soul of the child came into him again, and he revived.

- The son of the shunammite, 2 Kings 4.18-34, when he is placed on Elisha's bed and Elisha covers him with his body.

> And she went up, and laid him on the bed of the man of God [...] And
> he went up, and lay upon the child, and put his mouth upon his mouth,
> and his eyes upon his eyes, and his hands upon his hands: and he
> stretched himself upon the child; and the flesh of the child waxed
> warm.

- The man thrown into Elijah's grave, when he lay next to Elijah in the grave and touched the prophet's bones. 2 Kings 13.21

> And it came to pass, as they
> were burying a man, that, behold, they spied a band of men; and they
> cast the man into the sepulchre of Elisha: and when the man was let
> down, and touched the bones of Elisha, he revived, and stood up on his
> feet.

### Physical resurrections during Christ's ministry

Similarly the Bible records three resurrections during Christ's ministry

- Jairus' daughter in Mark 5.41, after he told her to arise.

> And he took the damsel by the hand, and said unto her, Talitha cumi;
> which is, being interpreted, Damsel, I say unto thee, arise. And
> straightway the damsel arose, and walked; for she was of the age of
> twelve years. And they were astonished with a great astonishment.

- The young man at Nain (Luke 7:14-15), whom he commanded to arise:

> And he came and touched the bier: and they that bare him stood still.
> And he said, Young man, I say unto thee, Arise. And he that was dead
> sat up, and began to speak. And he delivered him to his mother.

- Lazarus, when Jesus cried "come forth!" in John 11.38-34.

> When he had said these things, he cried out with a loud voice,
> “Lazarus, come out.” The man who had died came out, lhis hands and
> feet bound with linen strips, and his face wrapped with a cloth.
> Jesus said to them, “Unbind him, and let him go.”

### Other types for the resurrection

There are many other types for the resurrection, that is, for the fulfillment of the Promise:

- The passing of Israel from Egypt to the promise can also be viewed as a type of resurrection.
- Similarly bringing Joseph's bones up from Egypt is a type of resurrection.
- The bones animated in the valley of dry bones in Ezekiel's prophecy
- Joseph being lifted out of the pit
- Daniel emerging from the lion's den
- The prodigal son returning to the father

### Resurrection from Sheol

By this we mean, that traditional jewish beliefs were similar to beliefs held by the Egyptians and the Greeks, that there was a pit or cavern below in which the spirits of the dead resided, and then we can ask
about those being lifted out of those dim places and put next to the glory of God.

- Matthew 21.32

> I am the God of Abraham, and the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob?
> God is not the God of the dead, but of the living.

Similarly we see Jesus talking to Elijah and Moses during the transfiguration. (Matt 17.2-3)

### What type of resurrection and from which death

So given that we have these six physical resurrections and several "spiritual elevations" and other deliverances that ocurred chronologically before Christ's death, in what way can we say that Christ was "firstborn" from the dead?

Let's go back and see what the context of the passage is (Col 1.13-18):

> Who hath **delivered us from the power of darkness**, and hath translated
> us into the kingdom of his dear Son: In whom we have redemption
> through his blood, even the forgiveness of sins: Who is the image of
> the invisible God, the firstborn of every creature: For by him were
> all things created, that are in heaven, and that are in earth, visible
> and invisible, whether they be thrones, or dominions, or
> principalities, or powers: all things were created by him, and for
> him: And he is before all things, and by him all things consist. **And
> he is the head of the body, the church: who is the beginning, the
> firstborn from the dead**; that in all things he might have the
> preeminence.

The key is the true resurrection, that is *passing from the kingdom of darkness into life*.

How does Christ relate to this true resurrection?

In the conversation with Nicodemus, when Christ explains that he must be born from above, he says (John 3.13)

> And no man hath ascended up to heaven, but he that came down from
> heaven, even the Son of man which is in heaven.

So here Christ is saying that *no man* can go to heaven except for Christ. So then how can Elijah ascend to Heaven? How can Enoch be translated? It is only because they saw the promise through faith and thus Christ was born within them and it is Christ that is ascending.

Isaiah 55.11

> So shall my word be that goeth forth out of my mouth: it shall not
> return unto me void, but it shall accomplish that which I please, and
> it shall prosper in the thing whereto I sent it.

There is a whole group of people who saw the Promise, from Abel (Heb 11.3) to Abraham (John 8.56 - *Abraham rejoiced at seeing my day. He saw it and was glad*) to Moses (John 5.46). This group of believers is called the body, and in the new testament, it is called the church, but Christ is the head of this body and Christ is the head, or first, because he came from God, gave life to these saints, and then their resurrection was his returning to God.

Now revival from physical death is just a temporary resurrection before eventual physical death and so is a type or pattern for obtaining eternal life, which is the true resurrection being discussed in Colossians. The "return of the word" is that resurrection, and we participate in it because the Father's word has descended, dwelt within us, and become our life, but as it is always the Word returning to the Father, he is always the firstborn of the dead, and we are second, participating in that resurrection only because the word has descended and dwelt within us, through faith.

> “How can this be?” Nicodemus asked.
>
> “You are Israel’s teacher,” said Jesus, “and do you not understand
> these things?
>
> Very truly I tell you, we speak of what we know, and we
> testify to what we have seen, but still you people do not accept our
> testimony. I have spoken to you of earthly things and you do not
> believe; how then will you believe if I speak of heavenly things?
>
> No
> one has ever gone into heaven except the one who came from heaven—the
> Son of Man.
>
> Just as Moses lifted up the snake in the wilderness, so
> the Son of Man must be lifted up, that everyone who believes may have
> eternal life in him.”

Comment: In [1 Enoch 71:14] the Head of Days tells Enoch : "You (are) that Son of Man who was born for righteousness and righteousness dwells on you"... This concept appears to have inspired John's Gospel. * All Tsadiqim are the son of man.

Comment: I would enjoy discussing Enoch with you, but I haven't finished reading it yet. It's on the todo list.

Answer (score 4):

ἐκ τῶν νεκρῶν is [genitive, masculine plural](https://biblehub.com/interlinear/colossians/1-18.htm).

So, no, it is does not refer to the singular, female person called Mary.

It refers to the plural dead from among whom Jesus was raised, as it is written :

> thou shalt not leave my soul in hades . . .  Psalm 16:10 KJV

---

Daniel B Wallace states in p371 of '*Beyond the Basics'* that :

> In general ἐκ has the force of *from, out of, **away from**, of* . . . .

and the Englishman's Greek New Testament (Bagster 1870 edition)  translates the collocation as :

> ... from among the dead ...

Comment: Thanks for insight regarding the Greek. - The reference to Tehillim 16:10 would make David resurrected from Sheol  שְׁא֑וֹל  before Jesus though.

Comment: @חִידָה . . . .  except that Peter the Apostle of Jesus Christ refers to that exact text in Acts 2:27 and refers it, prophetically, to the death and resurrection of Jesus Christ.

Comment: ἐκ τῶν νεκρῶν can also be feminine, because masculine, feminine and neutral plural genetives all look similar usually

Comment: Good, simple answer. +1.